# MATLAB: Trying to add shared xlabel,ylabel in 3x2 subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, graphing

As the title says, what I am pretty to do is fairly straight forwards. I have a grid of m=3,n=2 subplots. They represent graphs of 6 different experiments measuring the same parameters. I would like to have a single x label and a single y label on the border of the six subplots. Unfortunately, I have not been able to dig up a simple way to do this so far. (xlabel simply puts an xlabel under the last active subplot). Anyone know how this can be done?

Oh, and how would I display degrees Celsius in the label with the degrees symbol?(the little circle...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [mtit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3218-mtit--a-pedestrian-major-title-creator) to create an invisible axes around the subplots. 
`mtit` returns the handle to that axes, for which you can then create xlabel and ylabel.

Example:

```
% create sample data
my_data = arrayfun(@(x)rand(10, 2) + repmat([x, 0], 10, 1), 1:6, 'UniformOutput', 0);

figure;
clf
ah = gobjects(6, 1); % use zeros if using an old version of MATLAB
% plot data
for ii = 1:6
    ah(ii) = subplot(3, 2, ii);
    plot(1:10, my_data{ii}(:, 1));
    hold on
    plot(1:10, my_data{ii}(:, 2));
end
% link axes to have same ranges
max_data = max(cellfun(@(x) max(x(:)), my_data));
min_data = min(cellfun(@(x) min(x(:)), my_data));
linkaxes(ah, 'xy')
ylim([min_data, max_data])

% Create invisible large axes with title (title could be empty)
hh = mtit('Cool experiment');
%set(gcf, 'currentAxes', hh.ah)
% make ylabels
ylh = ylabel(hh.ah, 'Temperature [°C]');
set(ylh, 'Visible', 'On')
xlh = xlabel(hh.ah, 'x label');
set(xlh, 'Visible', 'On')
```

This will produce a figure like this one:
[image: Example output]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the error you've got in setting `xlabel` and `ylabel` to each subplot.

Also I'm not sure I've understood problem.

The following code, generates 3x2 subplot each of them with its `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

In the first case each subplot has a different string for `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

In the second one the same `xlabel` and `ylabel` are set for all the subplos.

To add the "°" sign to the label, it is sufficient to define a `char` variable this way:

```
c='°'
```

then to use `sprintf` to generate the string for the `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

a=randi(100,6,20)

```
figure

% Each subplot with its own xlabel and ylabel
for i=1:6
   hs(i)=subplot(3,2,i);
   plot(a(i,:))
   c='°'
   str=sprintf('Temp [C%c]',c)
   xlabel([str ' ' num2str(i)])
   ylabel(['Subplot ' num2str(i)])
   grid on
end

figure

% The same xlabel and ylabel for all the subplot
c='°';
x_label_str=sprintf('Temp [C%c]',c)
y_label_str='Same for all'

for i=1:6
   hs(i)=subplot(3,2,i);
   plot(a(i,:))
   xlabel(x_label_str)
   ylabel(y_label_str)
   grid on
end
```

**Figure 1: Different xlabel, ylabel for each subplot**

[image]

**Figure 2: The same  xlabel, ylabel for each subplot**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use superlabel from:
[image]http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel